# word in list in tokenized sentence

Tags: python, string, tokenize

I have a list of words / appliances

```
appliances = ['tv', 'radio', 'oven', 'speaker']
```

I also have a sentence, which I have tokenized.

```
sent = ['We have a radio in the Kitchen']
sent1 = word_tokenize[sent]
```

I want to say that if appliances are in sent1 then print yes else print no. I did the below but keep getting no as the print.

```
if any(appliances) in sent1:
    print ('yes')
else:
    print ('no')
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: @JerryM. `any` returns a bool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this.

```py
appliances = ['tv', 'radio', 'oven', 'speaker']
sent = ['We have a radio in the Kitchen']
sent1 = list(sent[0].split())

if any([app in sent1 for app in appliances]):
    print ('yes')
else:
    print ('no')
```

#### Edit based on @tobias_k comments

Use lazy evaluation.

```py
if any(app in sent1 for app in appliances):
    print ('yes')
else:
    print ('no')
```

#### Edit : based on @ben121 comment

If you want to see with appliance are in your sentence you could do like this.

```py
[app for app in appliances if app in sent1]
```

Comment: Better use `any(app in sent1 for app in appliances)` to make use of lazy-evaluation.

Comment: Thanks. Works well. What would I do to print what app appeared in the list. In this instance instead of printing yes it prints radio.

Comment: @ben121 code updated